# In Metasploit, how to scan workspace's addresses with db_nmap?

Tags: metasploit

I have put some scan results from db_nmap in a msf_db workspace called "work1" and I would like to scan it AGAIN with db_nmap.

How should I shape my db_nmap command to do so ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

change to workspace work1 with command:

```
workspace work1
```

control data with command:

```
hosts
```

or

```
services
```

and run

```
db_nmap -p1-1024 iprange/cidr
```